# Fill Attribute-Values in XML-File by Java enum-values

Tags: java, xml, enums

I've got several xml-files that later define my GUI-representation with java/gwt.
for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <master>
        <search-field>ExternalIdentifier</search-field>
        <search-field>Name</search-field>
        <attribute allowDisableSearchId="MasterExternalIdentifier">ExternalIdentifier</attribute>
        <attribute allowDisableSearchId="MasterName">Name</attribute>
    </master>
```

In this special case I want to give the user the option to de/activate the search for specific columns by checkboxes. For identifying these fields, I want to give them a unique identifier (here with the attribute allowDisableSearchId). With this ID, it is possible to preselect (or even not select) this checkbox.

The problem is, when I set the names I might oversee, that the unique name is already given away in other files.
Additional to this, If I want to give an overview what unique IDs are existing (for example for setting preferences), I need to search all xml-files for this attribute.

Now, I was wondering if there's such a technique like I define an enum in java and set the values by the enum-Values. 
for Example, enum:

```
public enum ALLOWDISABLESEARCHID {
  MasterExternalIdentifier,
  MasterName
}
```

and then used in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <master>
        <search-field>ExternalIdentifier</search-field>
        <search-field>Name</search-field>
        <attribute allowDisableSearchId="ALLOWDISABLESEARCHID.MasterExternalIdentifier">ExternalIdentifier</attribute>
        <attribute allowDisableSearchId="ALLOWDISABLESEARCHID.MasterName">Name</attribute>
    </master>
```

With this I can be sure it is unique and can reference to them later in java-code.

Or are there some other techniques that I can use?

Comment: The idea with the enum will not assert uniqueness. I would write a Test, which reads every xml under /src/main/resources/.../ and parse all attribute-values. The Test should throw an exception when a `allowDisableSearchId' is used more then once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea with the enum will not assert uniqueness. I would write a Test, which reads every xml under /src/main/resources/.../ and parse all attribute-values.
The Test should throw an exception when a `allowDisableSearchId' is used more then once.

```
package stackoverflow;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static java.util.Collections.singletonList;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.junit.Test;

public class FindDuplicateId
{
    @Test
    public void idsAreUnique() throws Exception
    {
        final Set<String> ids = new HashSet<>();
        for (final InputStream xml : findAllXml())
        {
            for (final String id : readIds(xml))
            {
                if (!ids.add(id))
                {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Duplicate ID " + id);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    List<InputStream> findAllXml()
    {
        // TODO implement correct
        return singletonList(this.getClass()
                                 .getResourceAsStream("a.xml"));
    }

    List<String> readIds(final InputStream xml)
    {
        // TODO implement correct
        return asList("MasterExternalIdentifier", "MasterName", "MasterExternalIdentifier");
    }
}
```